# Windows phone 8 array to set Color.FromArgb

Tags: c#, arrays, xaml, windows-phone-8, colors

I would like to set the background colour of the grid using the colours array.

```
int[] coloursArray = {255, 0, 100, 0};    
GridBackgroundDARK.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(coloursArray.All));
```

The error is:

> No overload for method 'FromArgb' takes 1 arguments

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: Sorry but error message isn't clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `All` is what you're looking for here. If you want to use the values in the array, assuming they're in the correct order, you can do this:

```
Color.FromArgb(coloursArray[0], coloursArray[1], coloursArray[2], coloursArray[3])
```

If you're going to do it often, you could create a method that does it for you

```
public Color ColourFromArray(int[] cArray) 
{
    //add your error handling checks
    //...

    return Color.FromArgb(cArray[0], cArray[1], cArray[2], cArray[3])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide all 4 arguments a,r,g,b.